# Proving Injectivity $x + \sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove injectivity of a particular function (without calculus), but I've come across a bit of a problem. The function is:

$$f(x) = x+\sin(x)$$

I started by (abiding by common standards) assuming the following:

- For any arbitrary $x_1$ and $x_2$, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, $x_1=x_2$

So we begin:

**1.** $\quad x_1 + \sin(x_1) = x_2 + \sin(x_2)$

**2.** $\quad(x_1 - x_2)+(\sin(x_1)-\sin(x_2))=0$

**3.** $\quad x_1-x_2 =-2\cos\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right)$

**4.** $\quad\dfrac{x_1-x_2}{2}=-\cos\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right)$

I'm stuck at step 4. I know that, of course, if $x_1=x_2$, we get a true statement for all possible $x_1$ and $x_2$, but I'm trying to get to that fact (not just assume it).

Is there any way to break this (step 4) down further, or should I go down a completely different route? I'm really just requesting a bit of guidance.

**P.s**: I also tried assuming that there existed an inverse function of the form

$$f^{-1}(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + \cdots,$$

plugging that in, and finding proper coefficients, but that didn't work out so well.

Comment: In the title it says you are trying to prove $-x+\sin(x)$ is injective, but in the post you are proving $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ is injective?

Comment: @jnh: I think this is the type of dash used in expressions like : we had a dog  -- a large dog. But yes, one should be careful because it is easily confused with a minus sign.

Comment: @user99680 Ah, ok. I kinda figured that, but I was just making sure since it appears the dash was put inside the latex format block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know that $0<\sin t<t$ for $t>0$, or more generally $|\sin t|<|t|$ for $t\ne 0$, then from $4$ we have (for $x_1\ne x_2$)
$$ \left|\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right |=\left|\cos\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right|\left|\sin \frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right |\le \left|\sin \frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right |<\left|\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right |.$$

Comment: I don't think I'm currently in the right mind, could you help explain how $| x_1 - x_2 | < | x_1 - x_2 | \implies x_1 = x_2$, or rather how that inequality even makes sense?

Comment: Starting with the original poster's hypothesis that $x_1 + \sin(x_1) = x_2 + \sin(x_2)$ this argument shows that $x_1 = x_2$, since if not one gets the above contradiction.

Comment: @Hagen: Congratulations on the 100K .

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm pretty sure $|\sin(x) |<|x|$ is only true for a restricted domain. The first sentence doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan That iniquality holds for all real $x\ne 0$. Even with the geometrical definition of sine, $\sin x$ is the straight line distance from the $x$-axis to a point on the unit circle, whereas $x$ is the not-so-straight length of the arc along the unit circle from the $x$-axis to that point

Comment: @ArturodonJuan: (I know I'm very late) Think about the series expansion: $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I don't even know how I doubted that $|\sin (x)|<|x|$ held for all $x$. I look at it now and it is immediately obvious (more or less by the Taylor series that you wrote).

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use Calculus, more specifically the first- and second- derivative tests to show that the function is injective. More specifically, we show that the function is monotone and non-decreasing. From this it follows ( for a Real-valued function of a Real variable) that the function must be injective:

Using calculus, you see that all the critical values x are those for which $f'(x)=cosx+1 =0 $ at $x= \pi/2+ 2k\pi$ . Using the second derivative test, you see that, for all the critical values $x$ we get that  $f''(x)=-sinx =-sin(\pi/2+ 2k\pi)<0$, you get that the values at the critical points are all local maxima, so your function is strictly non-decreasing, i.e., it is monotone non-increasing, so it is injective.