Check injectivity for $f(x)=x+\sin(x)+7$; given that $f:\mathbb{R}->\mathbb{R}$
It was a homework problem.
I know three ways of checking injectivity. All of which confuse me.
One is the horizontal line test. That is, making the graph and checking for more than one point of intersection with any horizontal line parallel to x-axis.
Second is differentiating and checking if Maxima and Minima exist, which if they do, will cause the graph to fail the horizontal line test and make the function non-injective.
And the third is the algebraic method, which is hairy.
I used the second method and on differentiating, I got f'(x)=cos(x)+1. Which has multiple minima. So, it should be non-injective.
The answer however says otherwise…
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better way of checking for injectivity?

What has multiple minima, are you saying? Not $f$, for sure!

@HansLundmark, yes, I got it now. I was checking for local minima, not the global minima.

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/807182/42969,

Method two, the way you wrote it, isn't quite right. The problem is that a point where $f'(x) = 0$ might not be a local minimum or a local maximum. For example, the function $f(x) = x^3$ has its derivative vanish at the origin, but this function is injective.
In fact, that's what's going on for your function too -- but you have to prove it. As a hint, note that although the derivative is zero from time to time, it's never negative.

Oh I see, so the graph might be going upwards but getting flat from time to time, right? Like steps. So, that way the graph never fails the horizontal line test. I didn't think of that. Got it now!

Here is another approach; the mean value theorem is your friend.
Note that $f'(x) = 1+ \cos x$, and $f'(x) \ge 0$, so $f$ is non decreasing. Furthermore, $f'(x) = 0$ iff $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$.
It suffices to show that $f$ is strictly increasing on any of the intervals
$[n \pi, (n+2)\pi]$, where $n$ is odd. (Why?)
Suppose $x,y \in [n \pi, (n+2)\pi]$ and $x<y$. Note that $f'(z)>0$ for $z \in (n \pi, (n+2)\pi)$. The mean value theorem shows the existence of some
$z \in (x,y) \subset  (n \pi, (n+2)\pi)$ such that $f(y)-f(x) = f'(z) (y-x)$ and this quantity is strictly $>0$.

Ohh, yes, I've been taught this too, and now I understand it clearly! Thank you! I think it's still basically referring to the horizontal line test, right? Makes sense now. Thank you!
